# Mostrar Input segun lo seleccionado en un Select

Tags: html5, angularjs

Estoy intentando mostrar/ocultar un input según lo que se ha seleccionado en un Select pero no lo consigo

**HTML**

```
<section class="row nm">
                            <div class="column g-12 nbp denunciaMsg">
                                <mm-msg description="{{apResumenHogar.msgText}}" type="info" title="">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="column g-6 fg twoFieldRow">
                                    <select ng-class="{'likePlaceholder': !resumenVidaCtrl.comboVal}" ng-model="resumenVidaCtrl.comboVal" style="width: 80%;">
                                        <option value="{{item.codigo}}" ng-repeat="item in resumenVidaCtrl.masterTipoBeneficiario">{{item.descripcion}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wrapInput beneficiario" ng-if="resumenVidaCtrl.contratacionData.beneficiarios[0].codigo === 'O'">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="320" name="otrosBeneficiarios" id="otrosBeneficiarios" ng-model="resumenVidaCtrl.textoBeneficiarios" placeholder="Indica Nombre y DNI de los beneficiarios">
                                    <label><span class="help">Si hay más de un beneficiario sepáralos con una coma (,). Ej. Juan López Pérez 50123456Z, José Domínguez López 50234567X.<br/>También puedes designar beneficiarios con un texto libre Ej. Mis hijos.</span></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
```

En las opciones del select el value es *1, 2, 3, 0* y si selecciono la opción *0* me tendría que aparecer el input. no sé si es más conveniente usar ng-if, ng-show o ng-hide.

**AngularJS**

```
function continuar () {
        $rootScope.respuesta = false;
         if (vm.contratacionData.beneficiarios[0].codigo === 'O') {

        } 
    }
```

Sinceramente no sé como hacer el if para mostrar el input, he ido probando con varios ejemplos sacados de internet y nada o me sigue sin mostrar o me da un error y no me carga ningún dato de la ventana.

Me podríais ayudar o dar unas directrices a seguir para poder crear la función para mostrar u ocultar el input al seleccionar la opción en el Select?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No necesitas aplicar la lógica para ocultar o mostrar un elemento del DOM en un controller de Angular... sólo debes validar que el valor del select corresponde a lo que quieres para mostrar u ocultar dicho input.. `ng-if="condicion"`

Comment: Cómo sería entonces `ng-if="resumenVidaCtrl.item.codigo.value === 'O'"` para que recoja el value del select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagina que creas en tu HTML un input; si utilizas `ng-show/ng-hide` para mostrar u ocultar dicho elemento lo hará sin problema y - *acá esta la diferencia con ng-if* - estará **SIEMPRE PRESENTE EN EL DOM**; si utilizas `ng-if` para mostrarlo, este input se **creará o eliminará del DOM** si cumple (o no) la condición que le diste.

Esto debería servirte:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.opciones = [
    { value: 0, name: 'Opción 0' },
    { value: 1, name: 'Opción 1' },
    { value: 2, name: 'Opción 2' },
    { value: 3, name: 'Opción 3' }
  ]
  $scope.selectOption = {};
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="app">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Opciones</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectOption" ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in opciones"></select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-if="selectOption == 0" ng-cloak>
        <label class="control-label">Input</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cómo puedo implementar este ejemplo en angular 9? necesito salga un input al seleccionar una opción especifica del select

Comment: El detalle de esta solución es que cuando envías los datos a la base de datos, se guardan con el tipo dato, ejemplo: -Si seleccionamos el la opción 3, al enviar los datos, los devuelve así: number:3 En vez de: 3 ¿Qué se podría implementar para que no arroje el tipo de dato?

Comment: De ser así, signfica que estas enviando el objeto completo, por lo que sólo tendrías que acceder a la propiedad correspondiente y acceder al valor. Ej => `const data = tuObjeto.propiedad`